# How to update a column when the same column in another table is changed ?(postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need A Function or a Trigger to solve this Problem??

customer_details :::

```
custid    name    creditid
----------------------------
   2        a        1 
   3        b        2
   4        c        3
```

balance_amount  :::

```
creditid   credit_type    balance
-----------------------------------
    1         rent        1000
    1         transport   2000
    1         food        1000
    1         fruits      1500
    2         rent        1500
    2         transport   1020
    2         food        1200
    2         fruits      1000
    3         transport   1600
    3         rent        2000
    3         food        1540
    3         fruits      1560
```

Pay_the_loan :::

```
creditid   credit_type       Pay      status
---------------------------------------------
    1         rent           500       null
    2         fruits         600       null
    3         transport      400       null
    1         fruits         500       null
```

once i update the `status` column in `pay_the_loan table` to `ok` for a particular `creditid` i.e..,

> (update pay_the_loan set status='ok' where creditid=2)

`then` it should `deduct` the amount from the `balance` column in balance_amount table and it should be updated i.e..,(1000-600=`400` in balance_amount table `where` balance_amount.credit_type=fruits and creditid=2 from balance amount table)

Possible post me a `Function` or a `Trigger` to solve this problem ?

Comment: `1)` define the conditions: when should the update take place? `2)` define the actual update statement: what should be altered , and how ? `3)` transform `2` into a function and `1` into a trigger. `4)` profit!. `0)` you'll need some PGs/FKs in the tables.

Comment: ok i wil go with taking an example like this which makes better understanding for this!! problem @ wildplasser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off restructuring a little, creating a `loan_amount` table with the original loans, and just make `balance_amount` a view that shows the current balance with all payments deducted. That way, for example, a correction in a payment amount will not make your system show the wrong balance.

A view that calculates the current balance for you could look something like;

```
CREATE VIEW balance_amount AS
    SELECT la.creditid, la.credit_type, amount 
              - COALESCE(SUM(pay),0) balance
    FROM loan_amount la
    LEFT JOIN pay_the_loan pl
      ON la.creditid = pl.creditid 
     AND la.credit_type = pl.credit_type
     AND pl.status = 'OK'
    GROUP BY la.creditid, la.credit_type, la.amount;
```

[An SQLfiddle with the whole setup](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3c360/1).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7846f/1 the same logic here is not working can u clear this...@ joachim Isaksson

Comment: @user2561626 Sorry, `IFNULL` should be `COALESCE` for PostgreSQL. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7846f/4

Comment: thank u for your help,i had a small query regarding the table i will post u the doubt later...

Comment: This is the SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3e6a7/18 Please solve this query ...@Joachim Isaksson

Answer (score 0):

You can update both tables in the same query:

```
update
    pay_the_loan
set
    pay_the_loan.status='ok',
    balance_amount.balance=balance_amount.balance-pay_the_loan.Pay
from balance_amount
where
    pay_the_loan.creditid=balance_amount.creditid
    and
    pay_the_loan.creditid=2
    and
    balance_amount.credit_type='fruits';
```

**Update.** I've read [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) of postgresql `update` statement. Apparently, I was wrong and it is not possible to update two tables in a single query. However, I still think that you do not need a trigger here. Just use two update queries one after another:

```
update
    pay_the_loan
set
    status='ok'
where
    pay_the_loan.creditid=2;

update
    balance_amount
set
    amount=balance_amount.amount-pay_the_loan.Pay
from pay_the_loan
where
    pay_the_loan.creditid=balance_amount.creditid
    and
    pay_the_loan.creditid=2
    and
    balance_amount.credit_type='fruits';
```

Comment: This is the SQL FIDDLE sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3e6a7/18 Please solve this query ... @mikhail makarov

Comment: Did you try my approach? You do not need a function nor a trigger. You can update the balance in the same query where you set the status to 'ok'. Do you understand what I suggest?

Comment: I've read the documentation of postgresql update statement. Apparently, I was wrong and it is not possible to update two tables in a single query. However, I still think that you do not need a trigger here. Just use two update queries one after another. I edited my answer.